# Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnsupportedEncodingException thrown by implicit super constructor

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, byte

I am trying to convert `String` into `byte[]`, but it is required that `byte[]` has UTF-8 Encoding. Found this kinda solution:

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

But that doesn't work. Why? Here is an error:

```
Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnsupportedEncodingException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: You have to wrap it in a `try...catch` or otherwise deal with possible exceptions.

Comment: This code works (just tried it out). What else are you doing?

Comment: Just NOTHING else. Just wrote that and this error..

Comment: Obviously "Just NOTHING else" (emphasis orig.) isn't true because you only showed a fragment of the code. Furthermore, that fragment doesn't include the class definition so we can see where you went wrong. Please stick with the truth.